# mod_wsgi apache and django configuration not working

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi

*Using Django 1.5, mod_WSGI 3.3 and Apache 2.2*

The Mod_WSGI module has been successfully installed into Apache.
I have also created a very basic project using django-admin.py called "check"

So now according to the Django Documentation on [how to configure mod_wsgi](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/)
I have entered the following code into the Apache httpd.conf where it looks like this -

```
<VirtualHost 192.254.132.95:80>
    ServerName bangtestwsgi.mbox140.com
    ServerAlias www.bangtestwsgi.mbox140.com
    DocumentRoot /home/bangwsgi/public_html
    ServerAdmin webmaster@bangtestwsgi.mbox140.com
    UseCanonicalName Off
    CustomLog /usr/local/apache/domlogs/bangtestwsgi.mbox140.com combined
    CustomLog /usr/local/apache/domlogs/bangtestwsgi.mbox140.com-bytes_log "%{%s}t %I .\n%{%s}t %O ."
    ## User bangwsgi # Needed for Cpanel::ApacheConf
    UserDir enabled bangwsgi
    <IfModule mod_suphp.c>
        suPHP_UserGroup bangwsgi bangwsgi
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule !mod_disable_suexec.c>
        <IfModule !mod_ruid2.c>
            SuexecUserGroup bangwsgi bangwsgi
        </IfModule>
    </IfModule>

WSGIScriptAlias / /home/bangwsgi/check/check/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonPath /home/bangwsgi/check

<Directory /home/bangwsgi/check/check>
<Files wsgi.py>
Order deny,allow
Require all granted
</Files>
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Currently my DNS hasn't propagated so I am using 192.254.132.95/~bangwsgi/ to access the app (as told to me by Hostgator)

The thing is that nothing is happening. There is nothing in the Apache error log. There seems to be sign that the wsgi script is even running. Can someone tell me what I can do differently to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works on removing the line

```
WSGIPythonPath /home/bangwsgi/check
```

And changing `Require all granted`
to `Allow from all`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you are going to `/~bangwsgi/`. Your WSGI app is being served at `/`, as defined by the first parameter to `WSGIScriptAlias`.

Comment: bangtestwsgi.mbox140.com hasn't propagated through the DNS yet Daniel. In fact even 192.254.132.95/ isn't working

Comment: If it helps, at a certain point of time the error log suggests that we could not import 'check.settings'. I was getting a 500 error then, but I meant to repair that and then it stopped working at all.